# Flutter MediaQuery.of(context).size.width values are different than real screen resolution

Tags: flutter, size, screen

in my Flutter application I am trying to get the real screen width (that can naturally be different on each device).

I am using `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` but I've noticed that the values returned do not match the real screen resolution.

For instance,

- On an simulator iPhone 11 Pro Max (that has resolution 2688 x 1242) I get `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width`= 414
- On an emulator Nexus XL (that has resolution 1440 x 2560) I get `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` = 411.42857142857144
- On a real device iPhone 7 (that has resolution 1,334 x 750) I get `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` = 375

Does anyone know why the value returned by MediaQuery differ from the real screen resolution in pixels?

Thanks

Comment: what is `MediaQueryData.devicePixelRatio` in each case?

Comment: and btw, why would you want to know physical screen width at all?

Comment: Yeah, just realised that that in fact they are logical pixels and i don't really need physical ones! Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [the size property's documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQueryData/size.html) :

> The size of the media in logical pixels (e.g, the size of the screen).
>
> Logical pixels are roughly the same visual size across devices.
>   Physical pixels are the size of the actual hardware pixels on the
>   device. The number of physical pixels per logical pixel is described
>   by the devicePixelRatio.

So you would do `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio`to get the width in physical pixels.

Comment: exactly the media query and layout builder constraints both returns the result in logical pixel

Comment: Thanks indeed, that't the bit I was missing, they are logical pixels not physical ones. I did try and I get the physical ones indeed with `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio` . Thanks a lot!